# GCP SDK gsutil rsynch not returning progress

Tags: windows, vb.net, google-cloud-storage, gsutil, google-cloud-sdk

When I run `gsutil rsynch` from the GCP Console, or a .bat file, the full progress data does not display (it used to I'm pretty sure.) I'm on vers 403.0.0

Here is the command:

```
>gsutil rsync -r -n \\xxxx\WEBSITE\xxx\pages gs://xxx/pages
 Building synchronization state...
 Starting synchronization...

>
```

If I run the same command, followed by a `pause` in a .bat file, the `pause` is not hit - the batch file terminates. glist (maybe others) do output their data to the console and continue on to the balance of the batch commands.

```
c:
cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin\"
gsutil rsync -r -d \\xxx\pages gs://xxx/pages 
pause <<<<< never get here
```

If I use .Net Process I can capture the Standard Out which does contained the progress data. However StdOut seems to close well after rsynch has finished.

Is this a bug? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend that you update to the [latest gsutil release](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/update).
I tested on my machine and also on the [Cloud Shell](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/quickstart-gsutil), both with the rsync version 4.31 and they display the progress of the command, listing the files being copied.

I reproduced the script on different environments and observed that the script skips the commands after the rsync complete only on Windows machines. I tested on Google Cloud SDK Shell and also on Cygwin for Windows.

However, on a Linux machine and also on Cloud Shell, the same script works as expected and it executes the subsequent commands after the rsync completes.

This behavior depends on the implementation of individual shells. You will need to catch the unexpected behavior and handle the situation in the desired way, as the solution differs depending on the environment.

Comment: The update helped, I now get see some of the StdOut on the console when the batch file runs.

I still have the problem that the batch file gets aborted when rsynch completes.

Comment: Please, post the log output with the error so that I can check it.

Comment: Log? Should I post the console StdOut?

Comment: I'm thinking my problem is with an ungraceful exit from gsutil for rsynch. Please try the simple batch file in OP. Does it hit Pause?

Comment: I reproduced the simple script for the gsutil commands in a batch file.

As you mentioned, the command window closed after executing the first gsutil command line, ignoring the next gsutil command line and the pause. So I can confirm that we observed the same behavior.

I will inspect the gsutil.cmd file to gather more information about this behavior. We may have to  have the Google Cloud Storage team weigh in on this as well.